# Can the UK parliament just declare Rwanda a safe-country for asylum purposes?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

Earlier today (15 Nov 2023) a UK Supreme Court ruling declared that the government policy of relocating asylum seekers to Rwanda was not permissible, due to the risk of relocation back to the countries from which they had fled.

As a consequence, there is talk of the prime minister, Rishi Sunak introducing legislation which ”confirms” that Rwanda is safe for asylum seekers.

Is this permissible under UK law/parliamentary conventions/constitution, etc.?

Whilst not quite comparable, could a government introduce legislation confirming other controversial facts? Ultimately could they confirm that 2+2 equals 5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it can. Parliament is sovereign in the UK, which means that the legislature is supreme over the executive and judicial branches. If parliament were to pass a bill which overruled the Supreme Court's judgement, that is what would happen.

The proposed legislative pathway is slightly more than just declaring Rwanda to be safe though, and - based on [Sunak's statement](https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/pm-remarks-on-supreme-court-judgement-15-november-2023) - will focus on addressing the issue raised in the court's judgement. In particular, the court [held](https://www.supremecourt.uk/cases/docs/uksc-2023-0093-etc-judgment.pdf) that Rwanda could not be considered a safe country because there were "substantial grounds for believing that the removal of the claimants to Rwanda would expose them to a real risk of ill-treatment by reason of refoulement".

Sunak proposed in his press conference that the government would agree a new treaty with Rwanda which would "provide a guarantee in law that those who are relocated from the UK to Rwanda will be protected against removal from Rwanda" and "make clear that [the UK] will bring anyone back if ordered to do so by a court".

Thereafter, to attempt to prevent another 18 months or so of the policy again going through the court system, Sunak will put forward legislation to "enable Parliament to confirm that, that with our new Treaty, Rwanda is safe". If Parliament agrees, this would stop the policy being challenged on these grounds in the UK's domestic courts.

Sunak went on in his press conference to state that he "will not allow a foreign court to block these flights". Parliament, via legislation, could empower the government to ignore injunctions or rulings from the European Court of Human Rights, or withdraw from the European Convention on Human Rights altogether.

---

The [Safety of Rwanda (Asylum and Immigration) Bill](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/65709c317391350013b03c36/Rwanda_Bill_as_introduced.pdf), published a few weeks after this answer was posted, includes the clause "Every decision-maker must conclusively treat the Republic of Rwanda as a safe country". 'Decision-maker' is defined in the bill as the Home Secretary, immigration officials, and courts/tribunals considering a decision made by the aforementioned. 'Safe country' is defined as "a country to which persons may be removed from the United Kingdom in compliance with all of the United Kingdom's obligations under international law that are relevant to the treatment in that country of persons who are removed there".

Comment: "..this would stop the policy being challenged on these grounds in the UK's domestic courts." Except for the Supreme Court, where it still could be challenged on these grounds, or not?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution No, the Supreme Court is just supreme over other courts, not parliament. The reason it was able to block the Rwanda policy in this first instance was that the government tried to enact the policy through existing executive powers, rather than through primary legislation.

Comment: So the Supreme Court of the UK is not supreme over the Parliament but the other way around? This is different from other countries where usually the Supreme Court as the guardian of the constitution is even above Parliament although Parliaments often have the power to change or amend constitutions. In the UK, it's basically just the Parliament then.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution That's correct.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: the US situation is less common than one might think. Somewhat related Qs https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64008/how-is-judicial-independence-maintained-under-the-principle-of-parliamentary-sov https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33781/notwithstanding-clause-of-canadian-constitution

Comment: Parliament can't withdraw from the European Convention on Human Rights alone. It would also have to withdraw from the Belfast Agreement that secured peace in Northern Ireland, which requires the European Convention on Human Rights to be incorporated into Northern Ireland law -- and the ECHR itself requires it to apply throughout your territory, so it can't be applied only in Northern Ireland. It would be astonishingly controversial for the UK to unilaterally withdraw from the Belfast Agreement.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution It's good to keep in mind that the UK doesn't have a formal constitution. It does have a series of laws and conventions which serve the same purpose, but to my understanding these don't have the same level of protection as constitutional laws have in other countries. The UK instead relies primarily on political precedent to keep parties from simply changing those laws.

Comment: @kenod The word you’re looking for is “entrenched” — there are no special provisions in the constitution to make it more difficult to change than ordinary laws. It’s also not codified, meaning that it’s not contained in a single document with the force of law. It is however, contrary to some assertions, a written constitution — the only alternative to that would be that it was passed down in oral tradition.

Comment: @MikeScott Parliament could withdraw from the EHCR and still refuse to withdraw from the Belfast Agreement - there's not a force capable of forcing them to do so, short of Irish republicans taking up arms again and starting a successful terror campaign.

Comment: @JonathanReez The Supreme Court would be highly likely to rule that it was unlawful to breach treaty obligations in that way. Parliament can withdraw from a treaty, but it can’t deliberately breach a treaty’s terms without withdrawing from it.

Comment: @MikeScott parliament is supreme so the law could literally say that it’s legal and the court will have to accept it.

Comment: @JonathanReez They could, but the other parties to that agreement could then consider the UK as unilaterally withdraw from the Belfast agreement. That's the trick with agreements, they work only as long as everyone is on the same(-ish) page. Parliament is supreme in the UK, not outside of it. Of course Parliament is free to claim what they want, even that they did not withdraw from the agreement after withdrawing from it, but it would be very controversial (although maybe not with Tory voters).

Comment: @DenisNardin the other parties could do whatever they want regardless of what the UK does. I suspect they won’t though because expelling illegals is not particularly controversial.

Comment: @JonathanReez expelling illegals is irrelevant.

Comment: @phoog it’s highly relevant because I suspect that Irish nationalists wouldn’t want to blow up the peace deal over third country nationals.

Comment: @JonathanReez that makes no sense whatsoever.  None of this has anything to do with any peace deal or Irish nationalists but rather with courting the votes of xenophobic English nationalists (if it worked in 2016, it ought to work in 2024). Anyway, my point is that the people whom the Tories propose to send to Rwanda are not illegals; they are asylum seekers.  Illegals can be deported directly without any need for expensive and controversial arrangements with other countries.

Comment: @phoog unfortunately deporting rejected asylum seekers is very difficult as well, making the Rwanda solution critical for the UK: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40433/what-percentage-of-rejected-asylum-seekers-are-successfully-returned-back-to-the. And Irish nationalists primarily care about Irish people, not about nationals from far flung nations.